# Get a list of installed web browser applications on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, browser, url-scheme

Is there is any way to get a list of installed browsers (such as Safari and Chrome) on iOS devices?

In my app, I want to allow user open a web pages using pre-set browser. It should not interfere to default behavior of iOS

Comment: Whilst methods exist to allow a browser other than Safari to open web links on a jailbroken device ([this way for example](http://lifehacker.com/5922339/browserchooser-makes-chrome-your-default-browser-on-iphone)), I'm fairly certain that it can't be done on a stock iOS device. Otherwise someone would have done it already.

Comment: I just want to do set default browser to handle http links in my app.

Comment: Can you make your question clearer in that case.

Comment: In my app, I want to allow user open a web pages in preset browser. It will not interfere to default behavior of iOS

Comment: Edit the question: click the edit button just above and add that info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the browser has it's own URL scheme will you be able to open a specific browsers. 
There is no way in the current SDK to get al list of registered URL schemes, thus you will have to check wether the scheme is supported your self, by calling the [`[UIApplication canOpenURL:(NSURL *)URL]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW50) method.
I'm not aware of any implementation of browser specific URL scheme's

Call `[UIApplication openURL:someURL]` with a `http:` scheme will always open safari, custom browser aren't able to override the `http:` scheme.

Comment: If we can get list of installed browser then we can redirect http:// protocol to URL-Scheme of the selected browser

Comment: I just want to handle http: link in my app only

Comment: @HuyTran Thats not possible in iOS.

Comment: This a handle list of used URL schemes: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Google_Chrome. However, one can catch only these web browsers installed: Safari, Google Chrome, TikiSurf, Opera...